# Facebook Like Box: How to detect if user already liked the page?

Tags: facebook

I have installed the Like Box in my blog, and I want to know if the user already like my page. I want to implement something like this to my reader because I want to offer them hidden contents if they already liked my page.

Is there an event where I will detect if the user already liked the page in the Like Box?

Comment: The accepted answer on this question does not answer the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the XFBML version of the Like Box, you can subscribe to the 'edge.create' event through [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe).

Answer (score 2):

As Kendall points out, the edge.create event only fires if they like the page while you're listening for it.

[Here's another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page/5100287#5100287) that parses the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] parameter that Facebook sends to every page tab app. One of the attributes encoded in the signed_request is if the user has liked the page or not.

Pretty slick.

Comment: is there a way to do this on a facebook like box that's on my own webpage, not in a tab on facebook?

Comment: We do need an answer to this one...
For example for a Local Wifi Hotspot thing. To provide free wifi access if a user has liked a certain page.