# Forcing Visitors to Liking Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a Facebook page.

We will start a giveaway. And we will give gifts to our Facebook Fans . They will give a **promo code** if like our page. BUt we want to sure, they are really fan of our fan page.

Because of this, I want to create a new tab which say "*You have to like this page for get promotion code*" to user . When visitor like our page, he / she can see content tab. If not, they can't see.

It was easy on static FBML, but know how can i do it with iFrame ? My tab is ready. Created a new app and then this app added to page.

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do. You REALLY phrased this poorly. You don't want to force your visitors to do anything. You want to know when a visitor clicks "like" and only then provide a promo code. Correct?

Comment: Dave, yes you right. My Engslih isn't so good, because of this, i was explaining it in short way. Haha.

Comment: I thought as much... @xanderer's answer below is what you are looking for I believe. In particular look at the accepted answer for the linked question.

Comment: Ah, OK. It sounded initially as though you wanted to force users to click "like" for your content before they saw the content. Have removed my downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to parse the [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter, it has a Boolean attribute called liked.

you may want to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page)

Comment: As a side note, I do hate it when facebook pages force you to like. Although do I understand that it maybe a requirement for some projects.