# Facebook Visible to connectino

Tags: javascript, facebook

Wonder if there is an option to use facebook visible to connection for fan page.

as we know, facebook removed the fbml tags for visible-to-connection, and now I have some application I have to do this thing.

Wonder if someone has code, or guide to do that on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in client side javascript.  It has to be done in server side code by inspecting the "signed_request" parameter that Facebook will send to your application.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page/5100287#5100287)  has an example of how to do this.