# Facebook Fan Gate Page with jquery overlay

Tags: facebook, fancybox

I'm basically creating a 520px wide welcome page for Facebook which I will upload onto the server and then Iframe it into a Facebook fan page. I'm doing this using HTML, CSS and JQuery rather than the old FBML method.

I've seen a lot of companies using an overlayed image to tease the user to 'like' the page. Once the user have liked the page, the content underneath is visible.

Examples:
https://www.facebook.com/redbull
https://www.facebook.com/smirnoffus

Red Bull - when the like button is triggered the transparent image is hidden to show content underneath

Smirnoff uses an image to give the illusion that the image is overlayed on top of the content. Somehow when the like button is triggered, the image is swapped for content.

Can anyone shed any light on how this can be acheived? I don't mind which one - Smirnoffus looks easier but might be a pain as everytime I update the content, I'll need to update image too.

Answer (score 0):

When a user likes your Facebook fan page, Facebook will reload the whole page.  You can then use server code to inspect the signed_request post parameter that they will send over. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page/5100287#5100287) has an example code of how to detect if they liked the page in server side code.