# facebook->getUser returns 0

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Facebook fan page and I want to check if the user visiting the page LIKES the page in order to show the content. It works when I am logged in as the administrator but when another account visits the page the `facebook->getUser()` always return 0

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'ID',
  'secret' => 'HASH',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

//Page id

$page = '215010578537112';


$likeID = $facebook->api(array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' =>
'SELECT uid  FROM page_fan WHERE uid =' . $user . 'AND page_id =' .$page ));

if ( $likeID ) {

}else{

}
```

Comment: The examples provided at [the Facebook Developers blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/) show that the `new Facebook()` line doesn't include the line about a cookie, could that be the problem?

Comment: hey by the way, isn't that app secret supposed to be ***secret***?  Maybe it's not such a good idea to be posting it publicly on a forum?...

Comment: its just a test app so I don't mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a fan page, you don't need to call an FQL query, since an FQL query requires that the user has first authorized your application.  Facebook will send a signed_request post parameter to your iframe fan page.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page/5100287#5100287) on how to decode that signed_request parameter and check to see if they are a fan of your page or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version, you shouldn't need anything special to check if they like your page:

```
// find out if the user likes the page or not
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

// content to show if they don't like the page
if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
?>
<p>Not a fan</p>

<?php
// content to show if they do like the page
} else {
<div>Is a fan</div>
```