# Facebook wall post shows a redirect loop error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

Iam trying to post to the users wall using PHP. It is not working. Please help me to solve the issue. I have used the following code.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
         'appId' => $app_id,
         'secret' => $app_secret,
         'cookie' => true
        ));
        $fbcheck= $facebook->getUser();
        //op($fbcheck);exit;
        if(is_null($fbcheck) or !$fbcheck or $fbcheck==0)
        {
         header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload'))}");

        }


        $attachment = array(
        'message' => 'It is a programming test',
        'name' => $details['jobtitle'],
        'caption' => "Sunil Kumar",
        'link' => $urlParser->job($details['jkey']),
        'description' => 'Jobslanda is one of the perfect job sharing system.',
        'picture' => 'http://jobslanda.com/job.gif',
        'actions' => array(array(
            'name' => 'Get Search',
            'link' => 'http://www.google.com'
        ))
    );

        $result = $facebook->api(
        '/me/feed/',
        'post',
        $attachment
    );
```

Comment: after redirecting from facebook get the `code` from the url and then check, because your `$fbcheck` always return `0`  Check the given link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484478/facebook-getuser-returns-0

Comment: Sorry ..I can't understand it . Could u plz explain please.