# getting the information if the user is a fan of a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with getting the information if the user is a fan of a page (fanpage) becouse sometimes this query

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=$mUserId AND page_id=$iPageId
```

gets me an empty result although the user is a fan of the page

I used this JavaScript method which returned me "resp.error_code" and "resp.error_msg" was "Invalid API key"

```
FB.api({
   method: 'pages.isFan',
   page_id: 'FB_FAN_PAGE_ID',
   uid: $iUser
}, function (resp) {
   if (resp == true) {
       alert('fan');
   } else if (resp.error_code) {
       alert(resp.error_msg);
   } else {
       alert('no-fan');
   }
});
```

but the code is correct as the application starts and what is strange it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work.
I try to get the user is fan form request just like in this post [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page?answertab=votes#tab-top) but it doesn't work. 
Help pleace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JS SDK you can check if the currently logged-in user has liked a page like this:

```
FB.api("me/likes/" + appPageId, function(response) {
    if(response && response.data[0]) {
        //user has liked the page
    } else {
        //user has not like the page
    }
});
```