# how to check if user like a specific Facebook page or not

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

how to check if user like a specific Facebook page or not from my website (using PHP or Javascript)

Fb App ID = 123456

Fb App Secret = `0123456789

Fbpage = http://www.facebook.com/mypage

my website = http://www.example.com

ex:

**if user like Fbpage then**

**say "u are a fan"**

**else**

**say "u are not a fan"**

Answer (score 2):

From the [Graph API `likes` documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes):

> ### Belongs
>
> You can check if a User likes a specific page by issuing an `HTTP GET` to `/PROFILE_ID/likes/PAGE_ID`. This will return, in the data array, an object with the following fields if the user is connected to the page.

You'll need a [valid access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) with the [`user_likes` permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

In Javascript, this might look like:

```js
var page_id = 123456; // whatever

FB.init({
    // ...
});

FB.login(function(response)
{
    if (response.authResponse)
    {
         FB.api('/me/likes/' + page_id, function(api_response)
         {
             // if empty, they don't like. if not empty, they do
            console.debug(api_response); 
         });
    }
    
}, {'scope': 'user_likes'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the likes end point (http://graph.facebook.com) this is a json representation of a user's likes , interests etc. Just parse the list for your page id.