# Facebook app fan gate showing non fan

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have performed the below and yet even as a fan, it is only saying "NON-FAN".
I have uploaded the facebook.php file and added my app settings to which I think are correct.
What have I done wrong?

My app settings are as follows:

```
Canvas URL: http://www.mysite.com/myapp/  
Secure Canvas URL: https://www.mysite.com/myapp/  
Page Tab URL: http://www.mysite.com/myapp/index.php  
Secure Page Tab URL: https://www.mysite.com/myapp/index.php
```

I've coded my index.php file on my server as follows:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
//uploaded into same directory as index.php

$app_id = "myappid";
$app_secret = "myappsecret";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>my app</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
</script>

<base target='_blank' />
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<?php if ($like_status) { ?>
FAN
<?php } else { ?>
NON-FAN
<?php } ?>

</div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId : 'myappid',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}
</script>
<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response){
top.location.href = 'myappurl';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page/5100287#5100287), usualy does the trick for finding out, whether user is fan of page or not.

If you want to do it your way, could you please provide `var_dump($like_status)`, after it's been assigned some value?

Comment: thank you - I just can't seem to find the "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas" advanced option?

Comment: it's on by default now if i remember correctly (the answer comes from early 2011, might've not been enabled for all apps back then)

Comment: var_dump($like_status); returns NULL :(

Comment: Also when trying this approach: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page/5331541#5331541 I get "signed_request was not found!" :(

Comment: Okay, where are you testing it? Because you will get signed request only when you're trying it on facebook (opening your tab there)

Comment: Yep testing it from opening the tab, ie: http://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage/0000000000?sk=app_0000000000000

Comment: I'd dare to say that something might be wrong with app settings in that case. I recently made fan gate app myself, didn't have problems with that.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok so were the settings any different to that of my original post?

Comment: actully yes, i see your page tab and secure page tab are pointing at index.php file. remove that, leave only http://www.mysite.com/myapp/, and https for secure one, see if that helps

Comment: Unfortunately no difference :(

Comment: that is odd, since both ->getSignedRequest() and function i gave link to are not working, i guess your web part is not getting signed request. If it's not the setup issue, i'm not really sure what it could be. I'd suggest experimenting a little more with settings, and reading about [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that the signed_request parameter is only available on first page load into the iframe – once you start navigating *within* your app, there will be no more signed_request. (So you have to save the signed_request or the like status into the session f.e., once you’ve got it.)

If you’re not getting any data even on first load, then var_dump the contents of the $_REQUEST variable, to see if the value is there. If it is, then most likely your app secret is wrong – because Facebook::getSignedRequest will return null if it is not able to validate the signed request by calculating the right hash using the app secret. Please *double check* if your app secret is really correct.

Comment: Triple checked and still no luck- all details are 100% correct. It only has one page to load, index.php :/