# Click Facebook Page Like and use website app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[ I have read something about this. I didn't get what i am looking for.. There are lot of people have searched / asked this kind of question. ]

I have a facebook fan page.
I have one website based facebook app.

FB users should visit my website. If they are the fan of the page, they can use that app. Otherwise they can't use it.

Is there anyway to do this without getting any permission from users?
I have a facebook like plugin on my page which shows whether i like the page or not.

Can i make use of it?
Give some clues to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Look into fan gates / fan gating

Answer (score 0):

If your facebook ap is added to your facebook fan page (as tab or something), then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page/5100287#5100287), to find out whether user liked your fan page or not and depending on that, show something like "like this page to access app" or show the app itself (this has to be done on the website based app's end).

Comment: Can you give any clue to do this in website app's end?

Comment: The link i provided contains code that you should put at the top of your page that's used as app, and then depending on status display something for users who liked page, and something for those who didn't

Answer (score -1):

```
offcourse you can if you have a app id by adding following plugin...
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
                app_id=**APP_ID**&amp;href=**siteurl**&amp;send=false
                &amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;
                action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35"
                scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;
                overflow:hidden;width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency=
                "true">
</iframe>
```