# Detect current facebook user liked my webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook’s API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Is there any way to detect the current logged in Facebook user has liked my web page.I have to  provide additional functionality for users who liked my page.

Comment: I think its NOT duplication. Question is "Detect current facebook user liked my webpage(regarding personal website)"   and you suggest question "How to check if a user like my Facebook Page"  Its totally different.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for hope it helps
[LINK](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/find-page-facebook/)