# Can I check if I did like on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook’s API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Is there any way to check with JS if I did "like" a Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL to check the `page_fan` table

Documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/)

Query like so

```
SELECT created_time FROM page_fan WHERE uid='$UID' and page_id='$PAGE_ID'
```

if a row exists, then they are a fan.

You can call the api with the javascript SDK like so:

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT created_time FROM page_fan WHERE uid=' + uid + ' AND page_id=' +page_id,
    return_ssl_resources: 1
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```