# finde if visitor liked my facebook page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Hi i'm searching for a way to know if a visitor of my webpage did like my facebook fanpage ?
Is there away to know it?
It is better if it can be done with javascript but is not a problem if it is in php.
Thank you.

EDITED:
and i want to know as well if the visitor did like my fanpage earlier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a way to know if the visitor liked your page.

You can check this page :
[How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api/5100287#5100287)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Javascript, Facebook provides a callback when the like button is clicked :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

You can find more details there :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: yes but what if a visitor did like my page earlier ? i want to know that to ?

Comment: it seems that you need some permissions to access this information. See http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?855989-Detect-if-current-visitor-has-already-quot-liked-quot-a-webpage