# Facebook - Confusion between facebook page and facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I want to create an app in facebook. But I have little confusion about facebook pages and app.
I created canvas app in facbook using localhost setup and it works fine for me.

**Question 1:**
My question  is top bar with like button comes in facebook app or facebook page.(Image included of some random app)

[image]

I'm also curious to know whether http://www.facebook.com/americaneagle/app_153839431317646 is facebook app or page.Because it is not in domain "app.facebook.com" and works like app (Not only this there are some other app/page which looks like webpage inside iframe )

If this is an app how to setup topbar with like in myapp

**Question 2:**

I was referring [Sephora](http://www.facebook.com/Sephora/app_320219751374530) (Just random app,nothing to do with this app) which allow user to see content only after we like that app which also not in "app.facebook.com" domain.

Can we implement same thing in app (app.facebook.com/app_name).

I got one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api). Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly got confused between an **app** and a **page tab**.

A Facebook **app** is simply the app that you see with the domain *apps.facebook.com*, whereas a **page tab** is an app which is used in the context of the page and comes as *www.facebook.com/page/appnumber*.

You can find out more about page tabs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) and implement it easily. Also [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)'s a link about Facebook apps.

Comment: Oh! thanks ! So actually I want to create facebook page tab, not app:)

Comment: Yup! And in fact there are many applications like *forum* (Google it) which let you create custom page tabs without going through the trouble of getting a server space or writing HTML yourself.

Comment: Is there any difference between two functionality-wise ? like something will not work etc.? I want to do promotional app.So page-tab is better option I guess!

Comment: I don't think there would be much of a difference in your case. And yes, for promotional purposes, a page tab would be much much better.

Comment: My app includes functionality like voting etc