# Facebook fql.query get user like status doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to know if a user likes a page or not.
This is the JavaScript code that I am using:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : '660879460653316',
    cookie     : true, 

    xfbml      : true,  
    version    : 'v2.0' 
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  
        var page_id = '476851132449446';
        if (response && response.authResponse) {
            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid= ' + user_id + ' AND page_id=476851132449446'
            }, function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                if (result.length) {
                    console.log('liked');
                } 
                else { 
                    console.log('dislike');
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

As a result I am getting an empty object as a response.
Whats the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Probably your application didn't request the `user_likes` permission.

Comment: And if you are trying to build like-gating you can stop. Facebook will not grant you user_likes in that case

Comment: For a non FQL version an old answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/10799470/368003