# Javascript check if user already liked facebook page or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my website, when the visitor visit my web, if they have not liked my facebook page yet, i want to show Iframe like box.
I have seen many code in the web as well as in stackoverflow, but it seem doesn't work well. Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'IDAPP',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    xfbml  : true
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var page_id = "PAGE_ID";
        var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id =" + page_id + " and uid =" + user_id;
        var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

        the_query.wait(function(rows) {
          alert(rows);
            if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                alert("like");

            } else {
                alert("not like");
            }
        });

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
       alert("not authorized");

    } else {
       alert("not login");
    }
  });
});
```

Request with login or not login or not_authorize it work well, but when check for page is like or note, it doesn't run anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api?rq=1

Comment: Like gating is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy so don't do it

Answer (score 1):

FQL is deprecated, and you would need to authorize a user with the `user_likes` permission - after that, it´s just a call to the `/me/likes` endpoint. You will not get that permission approved for like gating, because that´s not allowed. And you will not get it approved for "please like my page" overlays/iframes either :) - because the user does not benefit from that overlay in any way, it is only annoying.

There is only one possible way:

- Subscribe to the like event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
- In the event callback, store a cookie so next time the user visits your page you don´t show the overlay/iframe anymore

Problem is, you don´t get the information if the liked or unliked something. And the user could just clear his cookies, so you can never be sure. My advice: don´t annoy your users with it.