# Unlock content of other users in response to the owner's fb page is liked

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I run a Wordpress website.  I have many users who have content of their own.

I want to add this feature: if one user wants to see another user's content, then the user (who wants to see) has to Like the other user's Facebook page.

Is there any plugin to do this?

I am currently using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api) by [Patrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630413/patrik) from Stack Overflow:

```
FB.api({
    method:     "pages.isFan",
    page_id:        page_id,
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response){
        alert('You Likey');
    } else {
        alert('You not Likey :(');
    }
 }
);
```

But I actually need to also integrate `user_id`.

Note: I can get user id from `get_the_user_id()` function; I only need to integrate it.

Answer (score 2):

Like-Gating is not allowed any more by Facebook – and therefor they have removed all easy means to check whether the user likes a certain page.

You must present the same content to all users, whether they liked a specific page or not.

Comment: So,can't integrate multiple fb pages in one web site?

Comment: You can “integrate” whatever you like – but you are not allowed to hide content from users unless they like a specific page.